# What are the actual risks from forcing Spring to allow circular dependencies?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I certainly know that allowing a Spring context to have circular dependencies is discouraged.  I remove them if I discover them in my own code, and we tell developers we work with to do that.  However, they still have the workaround of setting `spring.main.allow-circular-references=true`.

It doesn't do any good to tell developers it is "discouraged", when they can clearly see that they simply have to set that property to fix the problem.

What are the actual risks or problems with forcing Spring to allow circular dependencies?

Comment: If project A depends on project B as a dependency and Project B depends itself on A, what would be the correct build order? If you want to build A it requires you to have build B first, and building B would require you to build A first. In very layman terms it is the old "Chicken-egg-problem"

Comment: Circular dependencies form a serious technical debt, see [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/circular-dependencies-in-spring). Indirections, uncoupling, facades, APIs and other solutions can be found. You will need to dive into some solutions inside your team.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS In the case of Spring it is bean A depending on bean B depending on bean A. The way to solve that is with proxies or setter injection, but both have their downsides.

Comment: It is not so much a "risk", but that some normal cases of creating beans will not work, and the "work arounds" (setter injection or lazy initialization), make some forms of initialization harder (e.g. not only in the constructor, but also in the setter), or introduce overhead (e.g. the proxy used for lazy initialization), and/or makes it harder (or impossible) to create immutable beans (e.g. because of the setter).

Comment: circular dependencies are unavoidable in large projects, especially in configuration classes. Internally spring(-boot) resolves that via `*Aware` beans and `ObjectProvider`, which, IMO, is even poorer than allowing circular dependencies, `spring-security` has another square wheel (`ObjectPostProcessor` and `HttpSecurityBuilder`), which neither looks robust. That is kind of situation when treatment is worse than disease.